# Джанго-админ загрузка нескольких фото за раз?

Tags: django, django-admin

Здраствуйте. Мне для проекта нужно иметь возможность загружать несколько изображений (различное количество) для каждого продукта. Хороший пример это любая почта там можно выбрать и загрузить n-количество фото. Можно ли это сделать если то как?
django-photologue не подходит, по причине того что ты должен сначала собрать фото в zip, а потом тока отправлять. Но сам я не погу выбрать несколько фотографий
версия джанго 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сперва создайте модель изображения связанную с Вашим продуктом:

```
class Product(Model):
  ...
  description = TextField()  
  ...


class ProductImage(Model):
  image = ImageField(upload_to='product_images/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S/') # здесь укажите куда сохранять изображения
  product = ForeignKey(Product, related_name="images")
```

Затем, в вашем `admin.py` файле вы можете представить `ProductImage` как `inline`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *


class ProductImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  pass


class ProductImageInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = ProductImage
  max_num = 10
  extra = 0


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [ProductImageInline,]

admin.site.register(ProductImage, ProductImageAdmin)
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

P.S. Если вы хотите гибко менять путь хранения изображений, то используйте для этого специальную функцию:

```
def product_image_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # instance - экземпляр модели ProductImage
    # filename - имя сохраняемого файла
    # Изображение будет сохранено в MEDIA_ROOT/product_<id>/<filename>
    return 'product_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.product.id, filename)
```

И затем передайте эту функцию в значение `upload_to` в `ImageField`:

```
  ...
  image = ImageField(upload_to=product_image_directory_path)
  ...
```

Comment: не подойдет поскольку каждую фотку придется выбирать вручнуюб а мне нужно что бы я мог выбрать 23 фота они пошли на закачку

Answer (score 1):

Если по документации:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Если по стеку:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183830/django-multiple-file-upload

[Django - загрузка нескольких фото за раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524716/django-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7?rq=1)

Запрос в гугле:

"django multiple file upload"